# How to clean my full suspension bike

Tags: cleaning, full-suspension

I have a full suspension canyon neuron and after each wash, I'm finding that just water doesn't cut it. Does anyone know of any good products to use when cleaning my bike? e.g Mucoff.

Comment: Bike specific cleaners are generally good at what they're for.  Are you following the written instructions properly?  Warm water works better than hot.

Comment: Product recommendations are not allowed so you may consider rewording the question for advice on steps to take when cleaning. I've found the plastic brushes work well in combination with bike cleaner to get stubborn crud off. You need something to agitate the stuck on dirt from the surface.

Comment: Please use Edit to add more info - what's wrong with the bike after the wash?  Is it still dirty?  Or is it dull and lacking in shine?  If you're riding on sand or rocks, is it paint abrasion ?

Comment: Why would someone *ever* clean a bike???

Comment: @Daniel - If you ever saw my bike after a great days winter MTBing, and saw the look on my wife's face when I went to bring it inside, you would understand why. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If  I want to get it "Concours d'elegance" clean, I use dish washing detergent.

Unlike a car, a bicycle has no issue with stripping off the wax polish that protects the paint work (I don't know anyone that polishes their bike), and the dirt is mostly muddy organic materials that needs a mild soap/detergent. (Spots of oil from a over oiled chain or hub are dealt with using a concentrated dish wash liquid/water solution).

Main thing to do is keep any contamination off the disk brakes, hence the need for plain cleaners. You can go to the bike shop and buy bike specific cleaners in small, bike wash sized bottles, but I prefer to buy a gallon of basic cleaner and spend the change on things that matter, like a good coffee :)

Cleaning to me means removing the grindy stuff from around the moving bits and lubrication of the moving bits. Normally my only focus for "Shiny clean" is the shock and fork stanchions, after all, its a mountain bike -a bit of dirt gives you street cred and makes the bike legitimate...